# Breaking determinacy with forcing, and then fixing it

Tags: lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory, determinacy

While forcing is usually presented over models of ZFC, it works equally well over models of ZF (or even less). However, the *general theory* of forcing becomes much stranger (much like the general theory of ZF itself). One natural thing to do is to restrict attention to models of ZF where choice fails in a "nice" way - namely, models of the *axiom of determinacy*. A natural question here - in analogy with the AC case - is what forcings preserve AD. I have asked this [before](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109647/which-forcings-preserve-some-determinacy), thinking that it was an easy question, but I now suspect it is quite hard.

What I want to ask here is a weakening of that question, which I hope admits an easier answer (or at least easier progress). Suppose $V\models ZF+AD$ (and maybe additional axioms - $DC$ is natural, and I'm even happy with $V=L(\mathbb{R})$, $AD^+$, large cardinals, etc. if they'll help), and $\mathbb{P}$ is a forcing notion in $V$. Now, $V^\mathbb{P}$ may not satisfy $AD$; but all is not yet lost. Perhaps there is a forcing $\mathbb{Q}\in V^\mathbb{P}$ which re-forces AD.

Precisely, this is my question:

> Assume $V\models ZF+AD$ (plus whatever additional axioms are helpful). What are some necessary or sufficient conditions for a forcing $\mathbb{P}\in V$ to have the property $$\exists \mathbb{Q}\in V^\mathbb{P}(\Vdash_\mathbb{Q} AD)^{V^\mathbb{P}}?$$

In the language of [modal logic of forcing](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509616), I'm basically asking to what extent $AD$ is a switch.

Let me admit my ignorance: I am not aware of the status of *any* nontrivial forcing! ("Nontrivial" being relative to this context; e.g. we need the forcing in question to break $AD$ in the first place.) For instance, Prikry forcing at $\omega_1$ clearly destroys $AD$ (we get a countable sequence of sets of reals with no choice sequence), but I have no idea whether it *permanently* destroys $AD$. Similarly, I see no reason why the answer shouldn't be "all of them," although I suspect it won't be simply because that would be too nice.

*Note: all forcings are set forcings here. The "inner-model-theory" tag is a guess on my part.*

Comment: Here is one necessary condition: if $\mathbb{V}[G] \models AC$ then no further forcing extension of $\mathbb{V}[G]$ models $AD$ (since $AC$ is preserved under forcing extensions). So for example if we start with a model of $AD + \mathbb{V} = \mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R})$ and force to add a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ then no further extension models $AD$...